# uitable view gives whole black screen - swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift2, storyboard

I am facing this weird problem, I have table view at my view which shows a whole black screen as it loads, I have changed the table view with new one still I am facing the same problem what might be the issue? I have same table view on other view which is working perfectly fine. and it's really annoying.

Is this a bug, or is there some subtle way of fixing this issue permanently?

[image]

The black section in this picture is my tableview, all it shows is black screen.

Comment: We need more informations, like part of code, to help you.

Comment: Did you connect delegate and datasource correctly?

Comment: Please post you code here.

Comment: this problem is some how related to storyboard, i have same scenario at another view with same tableview and same code which is working all right. and yes i have connected my delegate and datasource correctly.

Comment: Dili any thing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/360513/dili